# Seperating an object

Tags: modeling

I am quite new to blender so it's a search for advice rather than an issue.

So, I'm creating a computer mouse, and I want to separate the sides from the main body, however, I do not know how to do it.

After some research I found the Bisect tool, however, that leaves me with triangle faces on top and then one large face (highlighted).

Is there a better way to do this?

Are the triangles that big of a problem? (It will be used for 3d printing not animation or rendering)

Is there an automatic way of separating that large face to match the rest of the body?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Actually it's always better to work with as few polygons as possible and only add geometry when you're glad with the general shape, but it may not be a problem here if you don't plan to change your object later, so you could leave it as it is

Comment: I see, I thought there might be problems with having such a large face and triangles. Unfortunately, I would also want to do some more editing e.g. add a stick that's facing out of the side that can be inserted into the main body

Comment: it depends on your final goal, is it made to print, or is it for an image/animation? etc... For your stick you can simply use boolean to add it

Answer (score 1):

Select the faces of the mesh you want to seperate. Hit P key in the keyboard. That seperates the mesh from the main object and leave you with 2 object. Tab out of edit mode and you will have side as a different object.